# How many chapters does the GATE Manga have?

Tags: gate

I'm really enjoying the GATE Series, having watched the anime, as well as in the process of reading the manga. I'm also in the process of getting my hands on the novels of the series.

However, I've only made it up to Chapter 105, namely the chapter where Lelei tries to open another GATE for the JSDF. To me, that can't be the end of the manga. It's such an abrupt ending. After chapter 105, the trail goes cold.

Does the GATE Manga stop at Chapter 105? Or are there more chapters to be read?

Comment: The official web manga is on [Alphapolis](https://www.alphapolis.co.jp/manga/official/138000030) (Japanese). It is still ongoing and it's a monthly serialization. Chapter 105 was just released on 30 July, the next chapter is planned to be released on 30 August.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Thanks for the reply. Originally, I thought that the manga had died off some time ago, like the anime did. But now that I see that it's ongoing, that is beyond awesome. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/41733/Gate__Jieitai_Kanochi_nite_Kaku_Tatakaeri), the *GATE* manga is still ongoing. Chapter 105 is the most recent chapter and, judging from the age of [its discussion thread](https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=1944988), only came out recently.

So there are no more chapters to read *yet*, but there will be. You'll just have to be patient.

Comment: I don't get it. Why the downvote? BTW, thanks for the answer. Those links are real helpful.